# UMVUE for a $NB(k,p)$ with $g(p)=p^k$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am prepping for an exam and this is one of the questions the professor handed to help us prepare.

$$X\sim NB(k,p)$$ 
where $k$ is the number of successes. Find the UMVUE of $g(p)=p^k$ if it exists.

Note $X$ is a minimally sufficient complete statistics so must find:

$$\sum_{t=k}^{\infty}T(t){t-1\choose k-1}p^k(1-p)^{t-k}=p^k$$

This implies: 
$$\sum_{t=k}^{\infty}T(t){t-1\choose k-1}(1-p)^{t}=(1-p)^k$$

Note that the infinite sum on the right cannot replicate the polynomial on the right since their powers will differ. Thus the only UMVUE is $T(X)=I(X=k)$ to guarantee equal powers on both sides. Is my logic correct? This will only work if $p\in(0,1)$ not at the end points right?

Comment: The UMVUE of what?

Comment: Of the function $g(p)=p^{k}$

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3827009/321264.