# Finding UMVUE for $p^t$ associated with a negative binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X$ be a random variable having the negative binomial distribution with
$$
P(X=x)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
x-1 \\
r-1
\end{array}\right) p^{r}(1-p)^{x-r}, x=r, r+1 \ldots
$$
where $p \in(0,1)$ and $r$ is a known positive integer.

Find the UMVUE of $p^{t},$ where $t$ is a positive integer and $t<r$.

I tried to use a direct approach to solve this problem but got stucked. I am wondering how should I approach this question using E(T|S) where T is the unbiased estimator and S is a complete and minimal sufficient statistic?

---

following what was suggested, I got
$$g(j)=\frac{(j-t-1)!(r-1)!}{(r-t-1)!(j-1)!}, j=r,r+1,....$$

---

This question has been well-addressed, here's a related question:
[Find EMVUE of var(X) and log(p) where p is the parameter for negative binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829495/find-emvue-of-varx-and-logp-where-p-is-the-parameter-for-negative-binomial-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is a complete sufficient statistic for $p$, all you need is an unbiased estimator of $p^t$ based on $X$. This estimator would be the UMVUE of $p^t$ by Lehmann-Scheffé theorem.

So take any function $g(X)$ which is unbiased for $p^t$ for every $p\in (0,1)$ and solve for $g$.

You have

$$ E\left[g(X)\right]=\sum_{j=r}^\infty g(j) \binom{j-1}{r-1}p^r(1-p)^{j-r} =p^t\quad,\forall\,p\in (0,1)$$

Taking $q=1-p$, this implies

$$
\sum_{j=r}^\infty g(j) \binom{j-1}{r-1}q^j =\frac{q^r}{(1-q)^{r-t}}
=\sum_{k=r-t}^\infty  \binom{k-1}{r-t-1}q^{k+t} \quad,\forall\,q \in(0,1) \tag{$\star$}
$$

The infinite series expansion in the last step follows from the fact that $$\sum_{k}P(X=k)=1\implies \sum_{k=r}^\infty \binom{k-1}{r-1}q^k=\left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^r$$

This can also be shown as a separate identity.

Finally compare coefficients of $q^j$ from both sides of $(\star)$ to find $g(\cdot)$.

Comment: just for clarification, when I compare the two terms, am I substituting k=j-t to the right-hand side of the equation? I sometimes made confusions.. I just want to make sure I was correct by making comparisons this way...

Comment: I think the solution is the same to what the other user suggested.. but isn't it just one all the time??

Comment: Yes you have to make that substitution. What is always one?

Comment: hi I think I simply made algebraic mistakes when I plug in values of j when I tried to verify the solution . I don’t  think I have any confusions for this particular problem at this point... but I do have a side problem. When I’m trying to find UMVUE for something like Var(X) or more absurd form, say log(p). Is it still possible for me to get answers from this comparing terms ? Are there more generic way of solving this kind of problems?

Comment: Assuming UMVUE exists and you can find a complete sufficient statistic, comparing coefficients as suggested here works for discrete distributions.

Comment: I tried to follow the same procedure to solve for $E(g(x))=Var(X)$ but still got stuck ... I got an expression that I put in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829495/find-emvue-of-varx-and-logp-where-p-is-the-parameter-for-negative-binomial-d. Did I made any mistakes? I simply replicate what you have shown in your post...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with Rao Blackwell. This is what I would do:

First: Observe that your negative binomial is the sum of $r$ iid geometric, say the Statistical Model is a Geometric replicated $r$ times.

$$P[Y=y]=p(1-p)^{y-1}$$,

$y=1,2,3,...$

Now I would set

$T=$  unbiased estimator for $p^t$

$$T=\mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}(Y_1)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}(Y_2)\cdot ... \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}(Y_t)=
\begin{cases}
1-p^t,  & \text{if $T=0$ } \\
p^t, & \text{if $T=1$ }
\end{cases}$$

$S=$ Sufficient and Complete statistic for the model

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{r} Y_i$$

---

I found

$$\mathbb{E}[T|S]=\mathbb{E}[T=1|S=s]=\frac{p^t\binom{s-t-1}{r-t-1}p^{r-t}(1-p)^{s-r}}{\binom{s-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{s-r}}=\frac{(s-t-1)!(r-1)!}{(s-1)!(r-t-1)!}$$

Comment: Hi, I think your answer is the same to what @StubbornAtom was suggested... but isn't it just 1?????

Comment: @JoZ : it's 1 only if $s=r$, say if you have $r$ draws to get $r$ successes

Comment: Oh sorry... My bad. Just for clarification, the unbiased estimator in your case is the number of trails we need to observe the first success right?

Comment: @JoZ : the unbiased estimator T is well defined in my post but it is not important...it is the easiest unbiased estimator I found...the first t $Y_i$ rv's with success at first draw

Comment: Yes I just try to make sure I understand what you did.... if the $\tau(\theta)$ is not in an easy form how would you find the unbiased estimator? I am struggling with the other part of the question, such as finding UMVUE for $\log(p)$...

Comment: don't know how to find it using either your way or the way the other answer has suggested