# Find UMVUE of var(X) and log(p) where p is the parameter for negative binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

This question is an extension to [Finding UMVUE for $p^t$ associated with a negative binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827009/finding-umvue-for-pt-associated-with-a-negative-binomial-distribution), I followed exactly the same strategy to compare the terms but got this weird expression when I try to find $E(g(x))=var(X)=\frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}$. I do not know how to deal with r, and it seems if I want to start from j=r, the right-hand side will have terms available starts from $q^{j+1}$. For finding $E(g(x))=log(p)$, I don't have any clue yet.

$$
\sum_{j=r}^{\infty} g(j)\left(\begin{array}{c}
j-1 \\
r-1
\end{array}\right) q^{j}=\frac{q^{r}}{(1-q)^{r-t}}=r\sum_{k=r+2}^{\infty}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-1 \\
r+1
\end{array}\right) q^{k-1} \quad, \forall q \in(0,1)
$$

Followed what was suggested I think I have a good understanding of how to find g(*) which gives $E(g(x))=p^t$, but it seems I still cannot proceed to the second and third part of the question. Could someone please give me some clue for the third part of the question, and possibly, point out where I have made mistakes for the second one?

The original question is attached below.

> Let $X$ be a random variable having the negative binomial distribution with
> $$
> P(X=x)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
> x-1 \\
> r-1
> \end{array}\right) p^{r}(1-p)^{x-r}, x=r, r+1 \ldots
> $$
> where $p \in(0,1)$ and $r$ is a known positive integer.
>
> Find the UMVUE of $p^{t},$ where $t$ is a positive integer and $t<r$.

Comment: You only need to substitute $k-1=j$ on the right hand side of your equation. The answer follows.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I will try to attempt it... before I start, do you mean I don't use negative binomial expansion but use Tylor expansion at a=0 or something? I am going to try it out now, just to make sure I am at the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't quite clear in the last comment. For the last problem, once you write down the equations you will find that you have to use a negative binomial expansion like in the first two problems as well as the Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1-q)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom if I expand $\log(1-q)$it gives me $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}(1-q)^n$, then I need to multiply it with $(\frac{q}{1-q})^r$ which I also need to expand... is that what you mean? I recognize the log form looks something I could expand but I just can't make it work

Comment: Yes.  And $\ln(1-q)=-\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{q^i}{i}$. What do you get?